# почему возникает ошибка: "name 'hours' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
sec = int(input('write time sec '))
if sec > 60:
 minutes = sec // 60
if minutes > 3600:
 hours = sec // 3600
if minutes > 3600:
 hours = 0
if sec < 60:
 minutes = 0
sec2 = sec - (minutes * 60)
print('results', hours, 'hours', minutes, 'minutes', sec2, 'sec')
```

Comment: Очевидно, что когда minutes 3600 или меньше, то переменная hours никем не создаётся и не существует

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: А вообще вашу программу можно написать намного проще https://pastebin.com/xCNMecsq

Answer (score 1):

Операторы `if` в вашем коде излишни. Попробуйте так:

```
hours = sec // 3600
minutes, seconds = divmod(sec - hours*3600, 60)
print('results', hours, 'hours', minutes, 'minutes', seconds, 'seconds')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникнет, когда вводимое количество секунд *меньше или равно* `60`, потому что тогда ни команда

```
  hours = sec // 3600
```

и команда

```
  hours = 0
```

не исполнится, и так в последней строке

```
print('results', hours, 'hours', minutes, 'minutes', sec2, 'sec')
```

(которая всегда исполнится) *не будет переменная `hours` определена*.

---

Найболее понятным решением мне кажется

```
seconds = int(input('Write time in seconds: '))

minutes = seconds // 60
seconds = seconds  % 60            # или:  seconds %= 60  (остаток после деления 60)

hours   = minutes // 60
minutes = minutes  % 60            # или:  minutes %= 60  (остаток после деления 60)

print('Results:', hours, 'hours,', minutes, 'minutes,', seconds, 'seconds')
```

или - с применением функции `divmod()`, которая возвращает *сразу частное и остаток:*

```
seconds = int(input('Write time in seconds: '))

minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
hours,   minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)

print('Results:', hours, 'hours,', minutes, 'minutes,', seconds, 'seconds')
```